# When using __bridge, will the object-c object changed to `__unsafe_unretained` implicitly

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Here is the code:

```
{
    CFMutableStringRef str = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 1000, CFSTR("Hello World") );
    NSString *value = (__bridge NSString *)str ;
    NSLog(@"%@", value) ;
    CFRelease(str) ;
}
```

The default attribute of `value` is `strong`, will its attribute change to `__unsafe_unretained` after assign it to a `(__bridge NSString *)str`. In my opinion, if not, `value` will be sent `release` method when `value` is out of its scope.

Can you show me how compiler handles this when using `__bridge` cast from CF to Object-C Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your assignment:

```
NSString *value = (__bridge NSString *)str ;
```

That has the same effect as writing this would if ARC were disabled:

```
NSString *value = nil;
objc_storeStrong(&value, (id)str);
```

The `__bridge` cast doesn't change the string's reference count, but the assignment to a `__strong` variable turns into a call to `objc_storeStrong`, and [`objc_storeStrong` retains `str`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-runtime-objc-storestrong).  This retain needs to be balanced by a release.

After the last use of `value`, the compiler inserts this:

```
objc_release(value);
```

This has the same effect as writing `[value release]` would if ARC were disabled.

Now suppose you wrote this:

```
NSString *__unsafe_unretained value = (__bridge NSString *)str;
```

That has the same effect as writing this would if ARC were disabled:

```
NSString *value = (id)str;
```

This time, there's no release to be balanced, and the compiler doesn't insert anything extra after the last use of `value`.  But if you use `value` after you `CFRelease(str)`, you will probably crash.  That's why it's “unsafe”.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have checked that, it is pretty correct. One more question, if I use `__bridge_transfer` instead, will compiler `CFRelease(str)` implicitly ?

Comment: Yes, a `__bridge_transfer` generates a release.  It's better to use the `CFBridgingRelease` function for this, because it's got “release” right there in the name.